# Jquery Smartspinner Reset Value

Tags: jquery

i use Jquery Smartspinner it's work fine but i can't reset the value in the function
onload i set initValue:3 when i set are new value in the smartspinner box he dont override the new value he set the old initValue in

thats the [plugin](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-spin-button-plugin-smart-spin/)

```
var duration = $("#bookingduration").spinit({ height: 18, width: 65, min: 1, initValue: 3, max: 62 });
```

now i have are calender and send the new duration in the box

```
$('#cdateto').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
minDate: $('#cdatefrom').datepicker('getDate'),
onSelect: function () {
    // diff
    var d1 = $('#cdatefrom').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('#cdateto').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 0;
    if (d1 && d2) {
        diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000);
    }
            duration.reset(diff);
            $("#bookingduration").val(diff);
 }
});
```

when the diff now 10 is and i press the key up or down then he load the old initvalue 3
i have trails withe are jquery val override but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly deciphered your English, you need to store widget to variable:

```
var spinner = $("#bookingduration").spinit({ height: 18, width: 65, min: 1, initValue: 3, max: 62 });
```

And call method `reset` when you need:

```
spinner.reset(diff)
```

Comment: it does not work, now i have creat are variable and call the spinner.reset(diff) the function hes no error but its not work when i click over there he replace the deff(10) into initValue(3)

Comment: It _does_ work. I just opened demo and run code in console. Value changes on `reset` and onchange callback calls as well.

Comment: Now you do proper `duration.reset(diff);` but right after do wrong `$("#bookingduration").val(diff);`

Comment: Okay i delete it
Console: Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'reset'

Comment: Well, ok. Is there anything else I can help?

Comment: the problem is the script for datapicker and reset is in ajaxcall the first build of spinner is in the index. i think i can't post the value in the ajax... i try are new way but thanks for your support!

Comment: i have found the problem look
http://jsfiddle.net/59wGP/1/
when i use more spinner, than come the bug lol....
Set by "to" are new date an hover the mouse over the Days i switch the Value o.O

Comment: Yes, can confirm it. Don't see anything wrong with your code in fiddle, so it looks like it's bug of plugin. Two ways to solve it: digging into code and fix it yourself or contact with plugin author.

Answer (score 1):

From Docs:

> ***Smart Spin plugin*** has a “**reset**” method that can be invoked over the
>   plugin, “reset” method takes one parameter, the plugin value will be
>   updated by this parameter value.